# data type to represent a big decimal in java

Tags: java, bigdecimal, jdk1.4

Which data type is apt to represent a decimal number like "10364055.81".

If tried using double:

```
double d = 10364055.81;
```

But when I try to print the number, its displaying as "***1.036405581E7***", which I don't want.

Should I use BigDecimal? But its displaying as ***10364055.81000000052154064178466796875***.
Is there any datatype that displays the values as it is? Also the number may be bigger than the one taken as example.

**BTW, will using BigDecimal effect the performance of the application?? I might use this in almost all my DTOs.**

Answer (score 19, accepted):

You should use BigDecimal - but **use the String constructor**, e.g.:

```
new BigDecimal("10364055.81");
```

If you pass a `double` to BigDecimal, Java must create that double first - and since doubles cannot represent most decimal fractions accurately, it *does* create the value as `10364055.81000000052154064178466796875` and *then* passes it to the BigDecimal constructor.  In this case BigDecimal has no way of knowing that you actually meant the rounder version.

Generally speaking, using non-String constructors of BigDecimal should be considered a warning that you're not getting the full benefit of the class.

**Edit** - based on rereading exactly what you wanted to do, my initial claim is probably too strong.  BigDecimal is a good choice when you need to represent decimal values exactly (money handling being the obvious choice, you don't want 5.99 * one million to be `5990016.45` for example.

But if you're not worried about the number being stored *internally* as a very slightly different value to the decimal literal you entered, and just want to print it out again in the same format, then as others have said, an instance of `NumberFormat` (in this case, `new DecimalFormat("########.##")`) will do the trick to output the double nicely, or [String.format](http://java.sun.com/j2se/1.5.0/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#format) can do much the same thing.

As for performance - BigDecimals will naturally be slower than using primitives.  Typically, though, unless the vast majority of your program involves mathematical manipulations, you're unlikely to actually notice any speed difference.  That's not to say you should use BigDecimals all over; but rather, that if you can get a real benefit from their features that would be difficult or impossible to realise with plain `doubles`, then don't sweat the miniscule performance difference they theoretically introduce.

Comment: Well, I think you're right. But a double data type must be enough for that number (only two decimals). Using a BigDecimal where a double is enough can cause a low performing when doing some operations.

Answer (score 4):

How a number is displayed is *distinct* from how the number is stored.

Take a look at [DecimalFormat](http://java.sun.com/j2se/1.4.2/docs/api/java/text/DecimalFormat.html) for controlling how you can display your numbers when a double (or float etc.).

Note that choosing BigDecimal over double (or vice versa) has pros/cons, and will depend on your requirements. See [here](http://fernandoribeiro.eti.br/2004/08/14/when-to-use-float-or-double-when-to-use-bigdecimal/) for more info. From the summary:

> In summary, if raw performance and
>   space are the most important factors,
>   primitive floating-point types are
>   appropriate. If decimal values need to
>   be represented exactly, high-precision
>   computation is needed, or fine control
>   of rounding is desired, only
>   BigDecimal has the needed
>   capabilities.

Answer (score 1):

A double would be enough in order to save this number. If your problem is you don't like the format when printing or putting it into a String, you might use NumberFormat: http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/text/NumberFormat.html

Answer (score 1):

you can use double and  display if with System.out.printf().

```
double d = 100003.81;
System.out.printf("%.10f", d);
```

.10f - means a double with precision of 10