# Can you explain this output of DecimalFormat API?

Tags: java, escaping

I have a number with value

> 0.947

Now, I use *DecimalFormat* API of *java.text* with the following pattern and RoundingMode-

```
double numberToFormat = 0.947;    
DecimalFormat restrictTo1DecimalPlace = new DecimalFormat("0.0%");
restrictTo1DecimalPlace.setRoundingMode(RoundingMode.DOWN);
String formattedString = restrictTo2DecimalPlace.format(numberToFormat);
```

Now, I was expecting the value of `formattedString` to be **94.7%** but its `94.6%`.
I know the value has been set to RoundMode.Down but then why does value of following are not rounded down -

- 0.9471 -> 94.7%
- 0.9447 -> 94.4%

Comment: check this link (https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/math/RoundingMode.html). It clearly explained

Comment: Checked it already, I don't know still

Comment: May be I need to understand Rounding down better but I was asking that why value of 0.9471 is 94.7% and not 94.6% like the earlier example in question

Comment: It's not rounding you need to understand better, but the behaviour of floating point numbers.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The closest floating point number to `0.947` is actually

```
0.94699999999999995292654375589336268603801727294921875
```

This is what your computer stores as a `double` when you write 0.947.

Rounding that down gives you 94.6%.

That's life I'm afraid. If you want exact decimal behaviour then use a decimal type! See [data type to represent a big decimal in java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1605910/data-type-to-represent-a-big-decimal-in-java)

Comment: `If you want exact decimal behaviour then use a decimal type!` Can you elaborate this please?

Comment: @Vishal: I've added a link to an SO question that contains more information on this.

Comment: @Aaron: But do be careful to use the string constructor to `BigDecimal` else you're back where you started.

Comment: @Bathsheba I've avoided constructing the `BigDecimal` from a `double` which would have been problematic. Is using the `String` constructor over `BigDecimal` arithmetics preferred? I hardly ever use them so I really don't know the best practices

Comment: @Aaron: I don't use `BigDecimal` either - as a scientific programmer I'm more than happy with binary floating point.